# I UV unwrapped my mesh, but the image texture doesn't show in my object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I just created a 3D model of a barrel and UV unwarped. That thing below is the screenshot of the UV image editor.
[image: uv image editor.]

Then I clicked new button below the UV image editors window and gave a name barrel and unchecked the alpha option, and selected blank to color fill option then clicked ok. then I changed the viewport to texture mode. I can't see the color grid texture on my object. Image below.
[image: full image]

i am using blender 2.78n thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UV unwrapping just deals with the coordinates for the mapping of a texture it does not assign the image to the material automagically.

In order to have an image be part of the material, you need to edit the material add an image texture node and connect the color output to the color input socket of the shader, then the UV coordinates as vector for the mapping.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. I am new to blender can you please suggest me any good texturing and UV mapping website or video. where I can learn from.

Comment: @AtanuMondal Yes, [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20beginner%20texturing) is chock full of tutorials, just search

Comment: @cegaton Thanks for taking the time to properly answer this question, this pops up so often and there was no good answer to point duplicates to. About time we get a proper reference for marking duplicates.

Comment: I recall that for 2.7x you don't need to hook the Image Texture node up to a shader, output, or any other node for it to appear on the target object when in the _Texture_ shading mode. It seems, though, that no such shortcut is possible in 2.80 (there's no longer a Texture mode) so a node setup like the one shown in this answer is required.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could also lie in your settings for the mesh if you've set max. draw type to something else than texture. See first post with image here:

https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/157177-solved-why-is-my-texture-not-showing-in-blender/