# Trying to add image to my model. I added in UV editor but it is not showing in render

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv-image-editor

I'm new to blender and am having a difficult time trying to understand textures.  I don't want to add a repeating texture but just an image.

I have added in UV editor as such...

[image]

It reflects temporarily in my 3DView window as such...

[image]

But it doesn't appear when I render..

[image]

What steps am I missing that makes my UV map editor changes permanent?  How can I make it render correctly?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86329/i-uv-unwrapped-my-mesh-but-the-image-texture-doesnt-show-in-my-object/86331#86331

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you assigned the position of the UV in the UV editor doesnt mean the software actually have identified your material.

Think of the UV editor as a guide to place textures and play around how you want it to look.

What you have to do is,

1. Select texture tab from the properties after selecting the material
2. Press + button to add a texture node
3. Scroll down till you see "open" button for texture
   (optional) since you had already imported to the texture to the program click the button on the left of the open button. it should list in the items.
4. Open the texture.
5. Render again and see the results

Comment: So UVimage/editor is just practice?  WTF?  lol.   How do I position my image correctly in texture tab?

Comment: OK so I selected the same faces... gave them a new material background color... then added a texture under the texture tab... then added/opened my texture image under the new texture... then it just somehow magically worked.  Seems ridiculously unintuitive.  Why couldn't the UVimage/editor have done that?  Anyway thanks.

Comment: UVimage/editor is not practice, of course. The workflow is 1) add a material to faces 2) add a texture image to the material (by default it affects only color) 3) set the texture mapping to use Uv map (there are other ways) 4) if you already had the image mapped to a Uvmap, it can be used, otherwise you need to. Quite logical and versatile, there are other countless and very useful possibilities, you just didn't know how it works...

Comment: Just because you know how to do it doesn't mean it is intuitive.  I find the Blender UI is an abomination.  I find the workflow for adding a texture is ridiculous.  At the very least the UV image/editor should be launched from the texture tab after adding the image in the texture tab.  Now that would make sense.

Comment: maybe I "know how to do" because I've RTFM? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/types/image/workflow.html
I do not agree but respect what you think of Blender UI, but probably you're used to other programs, and I could find their UI "an abomination" too...

Comment: @deanresin Note that any Renderer can do much more than just showing "a texture". A more general approach is needed that includes materials, which again can blend multiple textures etc. Not starting about baking. UV Editor and textured view are used to position textures, not to define how objects are rendered. The materials may or may not use the UVs at all. Node Editor is another way to do this, which might be more intuitive to you.

Comment: I had to open the same image twice, each time from two different places in Blender in order to add a texture to my model.

Comment: If its a big issue for you, try nodes. Drag and drop the image texture to the node editor, plug in the desired channel to the World output