# Image in material not rendering? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor

I decided that I wanted to start a mini-series in Blender, so I made the following character to start.[image: Original Character]

As you can see, I have made a face texture using an RGBMix node and an image texture node. Here they are:[image: Original Character Nodes]

After lots of experimenting, I finally figured this out and as you can see, it works. I decided to go on to make my second character. I repeated this entire process, but the face doesn't work for some reason.[image: New Character Face Problem]

As you can see on the right, the texture looks exactly the same, and I have checked it multiple time to make sure there is no difference. The nodes are also the same. [image: Node Similarities]

However, both in material view and rendered view, the face texture does not load. [image: Rendered view problem]

These two characters are exactly the same except for the hairstyle and the colour of the body and clothes. I have checked my work multiple times and have been unable to notice any discrepancies between the two. The only difference I have noticed is that in the node editor for the second character (the one that isn't working) the nodes snap to the grip, while the nodes for the first character do not. I am not sure if this makes any difference, but it is just something I have noticed. The last thing is that for the second character, the colour I set in the RGBMix node renders, but the face does not.

I would really appreciate any advice anyone has regarding this problem. Please help!

Comment: You have not provided your images with texture coordinates

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I added a texture coordinates node but nothing seemed to change...

Comment: Have you unwrapped your mesh yet?

Comment: No, but I am just surprised by the fact that it worked the first time but not this time...

Comment: Now it works, but the face is upside-down

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out just by rotating the texture. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Whitest post an answer explaining how you fixed your issue.

Comment: For a step by step guide read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86329/i-uv-unwrapped-my-mesh-but-the-image-texture-doesnt-show-in-my-object