# Checkerboard Texture Object

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]
After UV unwrapping and creating a UV Grid, I should be able to see the object  wrapped up in a checkerboard in texture view, as shown in the pic without nodes . However, I see no change. What am I missing here? According to this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiQOHSzyooc) (12:08), I should be able to see it  after the steps aforementioned.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magicaly appearing checker board ;)

The UV/Image Editor has the feature to load images from disk but also to create new ones. And one of the new image templates is a checkerboard, called UV Test-Grid. Your tutorial guy just had one already created.

Click on Image -> New Image and choose UV Test Grid and it should appear!

To also see it in the viewport choose texture as your view options and assign the newly created uv testgrid texture to your object (in the materials tab of your object)

Since thise is a UV Grid, you should have your object UV unwrapped in order to see it. So if the object stays gray you have to unwrap it first. If the texture then looks screwed up you have to properly uv unwrap your object ;) There are many tutorials out there that show you how this is done.

Create new image:
[image: Create new image]

Choose Generated Type "UV Grid":
[image: Choose Generated Type UV Grid]

Assign the new image as texture of your object:
[image: Assign the new image as texture of your object]

Make sure youe selected Texture in your 3D View:
[image: Make sure youe selected Texture in your 3D View]

Comment: Rad also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86329/i-uv-unwrapped-my-mesh-but-the-image-texture-doesnt-show-in-my-object/86331#86331

Comment: @Gerald Degeneve Don't see the UV Test Grid option "Click on Image -> New Image and choose UV Test Grid " Not there. Using Blender 2.79.2

Comment: Of course it is there. I updated the answer ... but really ... not there ? Have you even looked ? ;)

Comment: I would very much apprechiate it if you could mark it as answer ;)

Comment: That was the correct answer! It worked. You absolutely nailed it 100%! Thank you so much!!!@Gerald Degeneve

Comment: Please mark it as answer then ;) There is a checkmark right beside the Up Vote Counter. Click on that. Thank you :)