# Texture Colors Not Working

Tags: modeling, texturing

I made this 3x3 pixel png to use for the colors of this tree, but when I put the mapping on the colors, nothing happens. I made the image the base color, why is nothing happening?

My tree in the UV mapping screen

[image]

Tree now with color
[image]

Comment: it seems your 3d view is in solid mode: enlarge the 3d view and look at the buttons on its top right.

Comment: I see the colors now, but they are all weird shades, not solid color like in the picture

Comment: Could that just be a mapping issue or something else?

Comment: Consider uploading your file: the screenshot does not provide enough details. Please use this site to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've reloaded the page multiple times but it seems like the file isn't going through

Comment: You should obtain a link once uploaded. Paste it here

Comment: cool [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=KZ4EOlaw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KZ4EOlaw/)

Comment: Seems to be ok here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OFfN.png But as the texture was not packed in the file i've created another one (similar to yours above)

Comment: So it worked for you? Idk what I should do then.

Comment: Same version of Blender and on Windows too... so? Is it the only issue on this kind? Give a try with some base shapes

Comment: waiit I was messing with the options and I fixed it, I had "Smart" on instead of "Closest"

Comment: Okie I fixed it thx for helping, I'm very new to blender and I'm making my first 3D game so I've been trying to get used to the software XD

Comment: ok, good if it works. But that should not be the reason in this case. Here the result is the same whatever the image mode is

Comment: Huh that is odd. Whatever if it's good it's fine by me.

Comment: [I UV unwrapped my mesh, but the image texture doesn't show in my object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86329/i-uv-unwrapped-my-mesh-but-the-image-texture-doesnt-show-in-my-object/86331#86331)